# Zend Test assertResponseCode incompatible with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, zend-test

I am trying to use Zend Test and PHPUnit to test an application I've built.  I'm just in the early stages of getting things setup and have run into some problems ([see this fun problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041979/setup-phpunit-with-zend-test)).  But besides PHPUnit not being able to write the log file for whatever reason, the tests do run just fine (seemingly).  However, if I try to use `$this->assertResponseCode(200, 'some message');` I get the following error:

```
Declaration of Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Constraint_ResponseHeader::evaluate() should be compatible with PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint::evaluate($other, $description = '', $returnResult = false)
```

I've looked at the Zend Test code, and I'm pretty sure I'm passing the correct parameters.  I've also searched for my issues and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464933/zend-framework-unit-test-fails-on-assertresponsecode200).  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

I'm running the latest PHPUnit (3.6.12) from [here](http://pear.phpunit.de/) and PHP 5.4 on Windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389732/declaration-of-zend-test-phpunit-constraint-domqueryevaluate-should-be-compa, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092118/after-updating-phpunit-to-version-3-6-3-assertredirectto-fails, http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-extensions-integration-third-party-35/integration-third-party-tools-34/phpunit-3-6-3-zf-evaluate-errors-6266.html, http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11828:

> Closing as won't fix due to a collection of reasons:
>
> Matthew has stated repeatedly that PHPUnit 3.4.x is the officially-supported version of ZFv1
> Repeated attempts (both official and unofficial) have not yielded a workable PHAR archive of PHPUnit 3.4.x which could be bundled with ZFv1
> Alternate solutions exist (ie: altroot PEAR install + PHPUnit 3.4.x)

Comment: Note that downgrading solved this issue right away, but not my other problem.